# Input and store data into neo4j database through a website

Tags: html, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j, I want to create a website in which user can input data and the data can be stored into neo4j database.

Please can you tell me how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

FM

Answer (score 1):

Check out examples here: http://maxdemarzi.com

Or here: http://gensen.herokuapp.com/?tags=type%2Fneo4j-challenge&q=#results